# Is Vietnam addon for Bad Company 2 a remake of an old BF: Vietnam game?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam

Is Vietnam addon for Bad Company 2 will be a remake of an original Battlefield: Vietnam game (similar to how BF 1943 was to BF 1942), or it's a completely different game? If it's a remake then what features will be carried over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's a remake of 2004's [Battlefield Vietnam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Vietnam) only in the broad sense that it's a similar setting.

I do not think it's a true *remake* -- in the sense of having the same maps, same gameplay, and exactly the same vehicles and weapons as the 2004 game.

From [what I have read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield:_Bad_Company_2#Expansion_pack), it'll be the same (awesome) core BF:BC2 gameplay, but transplanted to new jungle maps, vietnam-era weapons, and vietnam-era vehicles.

> The [Vietnam] expansion pack will contain 4 new maps, 6 new vehicles, and 15 new weapons. It is also planned to include 49 contemporary music tracks which can be listened to via an in-game radio as well as new voice overs for both American and Vietnamese forces, based on authentic communication from the Vietnam war.

Comment: Ah, the in-game radio!  BF:V was worth playing just for those tunes.